# R ggplot2, is there a simple way to use colors for geom_point from strings in one of the coloumns?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with RGB colour strings in `load` column like this:

```
> head(ddata)
    YR MR WR DR HR    y  m w d    load
1 2017 10  1  2  3 2017 11 0 3 #FF8000
2 2017 10  1  2  3 2018  4 2 2 #4C9900
3 2017 10  1  2  3 2018  7 4 1 #4C9900
```

but running ggplot:

```
ggplot(ddata, aes(..., ..., colour=load)) + geom_point(size=0.1)
```

of course it turns these strings into random colours of its' own palette.
Is there a simple way to just make it use the parameters as colour definitions? Or I have to do those painful palette-creation manipulations?

Also, I get an error when using continuous palettes as shown [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html). With the same data but numeric `load`:

```
    YR MR WR DR HR    y  m w d load
1 2017 10  1  2  3 2017 11 0 3    3
2 2017 10  1  2  3 2018  4 2 2    1
3 2017 10  1  2  3 2018  7 4 1    1
```

I get this:

```
> ggplot(ddata, aes(..., ...)) + geom_point(aes(colour=load), size=0.1) + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Greens")
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
> mode(ddata$load)
[1] "numeric"
> class(ddata$load)
[1] "integer"
```

Although my version of ggplot and R might be old. But maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: Use `+scale_colour_identity()`

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks! it works.